# Detect version of the plugin in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, npapi

I have NPAPI plugin and I want to detect its version before I embed it into web page. If version is not the latest one I want to show some message that asks users to update the plugin.

Now it's implemented in the following way

```
if (navigator.mimeTypes && navigator.mimeTypes["application/myplugin"]) {
{
    // some code here

    if(navigator.plugins["myplugin"] && navigator.plugins["myplugin"].version >= latest_version) {
        // we have the latest version (embed the plugin into web page)
        document.write ("<object id='plugin'><embed ....></object>");
    } else {
        document.write ("Show message here");
    }

    // some code
}
```

The problem is that `navigator.plugins["myplugin"].version` works fine in Firefox but not in Chrome. Chrome doesn't expose `version` property. I can add my own property in NPAPI code, but I don't see the way I can use it before embedding the plugin into page.

Is there any workaround?

Thanks in advance, Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a lot of plugins have version information in either the name or the description. You should be able to access that information before the embed.

Comment: Yes, I thought about putting version number in description like in Silverlight, for example. But I wanted to find more elegant way :-) Anyway, thanks for your advice.

Comment: I'm afraid that's your best bet. I believe this is a webkit issue though, as Safari does the same thing.

Comment: Yes, looks like I need to set plugin version in description. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

I actually put the version number in the filename, rather than even the name or description. The reason for this is that if there are multiple plugins with the same name, description, and mimetypes Firefox will generally use the latest version.  Older versions of firefox have been inconsistent in how they handle this, so I even usually put the np???_version.dll file in a version-specific subdirectory.

It is a little bit of a pain, but it works consistently the same way in every NPAPI browser.

Comment: Thanks for advice, but it's supposed to be only one version of the plugin in system and I don't want to change plugin name for every release and create some kind of plugin "hell".

Comment: that's the point; you don't change the plugin name, you change the filename.  Of course you only go for one version of the plugin in the system... but when you upgrade it's easy to have one open by a browser and then you can't delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a JSAPI property of your plugin containing the version. This property returns the plugin's version when called from javascript. So when you try to insert/embed the plugin in the page, you can check through javascript to make the appropriate calls.